# How can I stay in the same Tab in yii2 after moving to different page in tab

Tags: pagination, yii2, tabs, bootstrap-5

I'm using Tabs widget in Yii2, and in the tabs of this widget I render 5 different views with  Pagination using LinkPager, my problem is that when I click in the pagination of a Tab to go to the next page, it changes my tab to default one (The pagination changes and remains as a get parameter).

How can I stay in the same tab when moving to a different page in the same tab?

I've tried to add a parameter in Navigation that shows the active tab in the url, but pagination doesn´t work.

Here it is my navigation, I use the same format for all pagination, changing variable names for making it different:

```
$pagination = new Pagination([
    'defaultPageSize' => 5,
    'pageParam'=>'postPage',
    'totalCount' => $sql->count(),
]);
```

Here it is my Tab widget ( I used 'active' for showing active tab as I said above, now for default shows as active first Tab)

```
<?php
echo Tabs::widget([
        
    'items' => [
        [
            'label' => 'Actividad',
            'content' => $this->render("@app/views/post/listado_posts", [
                            "pagination" => $paginationActividad,
                            "posts"=>$postsActividad,
                        ]),
            'active' => strcmp($activo, 'tabactividad')==0,
        ],
        [
            'label' => 'Posts',
            'content' => $this->render("@app/views/post/listado_posts", [
                "pagination" => $pagination,
                "posts"=>$posts,
            ]),
            'active' => strcmp($activo, 'tabpost')==0,
        ],
        ....
]);
?>
```

And finally, this is the LinkPager I use for each view:

```
<?= LinkPager::widget(['pagination' => $pagination]) ?>
```